# Writing point feature classes fields to polygon feature classes field in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-join

I have one database and two feature classes. One of feature class is polygon other is point featured. I want to write points names to polygon attribute table with commas which are intersects. my english is poor sorry. i tried to explain that with a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Use Spatial Join, select one_to_many, on the FieldMap, Merge Rule select Join, define the delimiter.

Comment: Where am i wrong? 

[1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YPGrM.png

Comment: Properties, select Join, define the delimiter. I guess it is 2 steps, sorry.

Comment: what should i write to delimiter?

Comment: a comma, not quote required

Comment: i think i am doing something wrong. it made multipart featured polygons 
[1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/4qYXp.png

Comment: Solved! i selected one to one and it is ok :) thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Spatial Join > select one_to_one > select to field what will join and right click > properties > merge rule : join > delimiter: comma and it is OK.